# Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document DJANGO PYTHON SELENIUM

Tags: python, django, selenium

I keep getting an exception for stale element when trying to locate the search bar...  
basically, my function will take passed in data (a playlist) and iterate through it to search each song on who sampled's website....   
 from there it will populate two lists, one with the "found connections" and the other list for un-found connections.
 I am using  CHROMEDRIVER

i just want it to return the two lists before i work on the algorithm to search for song name only and not the artist. since they are in the same div from a web scrape beforehand to acquire the data

```
def whosampled_submit(request, id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
        # options.add_argument('--headless')
        prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        #GOTTA CHANGE THIS TO FIREFOX OR EDGE
        # GO TO ---->    https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases TO FIX BMP ISSUE


        user = request.user
        AcceptedConnections= []
        exceptions= []


        specific = Search.objects.get(pk = id)
        songs = get_list_or_404(Song, search=id)
        for x in songs:

            print(x,'\n')
            song = str(x)
            # searching for songs
            driver.get("https://www.whosampled.com/")
            search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchInput"]')
            search.send_keys(song)
            search.submit()
            try:
                top_connection = driver.find_element_by_class_name('connectionTitle').text
                print("\nSAMPLE FOUND")
                print(song)
                print(top_connection)
                AcceptedConnections.append(str(top_connection))

            except NoSuchElementException:
                print('\nDID NOT FIND\nNO CONNECTION----->', song)
                exceptions.append(str(song))
                pass
            pass

        driver.quit()
        print('ACCEPTED')
        pprint.pprint(AcceptedConnections)
        print('---------------------------------------')
        print('DENIED')
        pprint.pprint(exceptions)

        context = {
            'specific' : specific,
        }
        return render(request, 'whosampled_result.html', context)
```

Comment: it seems to work when its not in a django project and just a stand alone script but that shouldnt be an issue since the data this function uses is from another function that used selenium

Comment: in which element you found an error?

Comment: search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchInput"]')      

code stopped working at search.submit()

Comment: try to add wait for getting element because of page load maybe there is no element in HTML.

Comment: I re wrote the for loop and it seems to work now. The div was found by getting the full x path again  thank you !